# Running ssh-add in bash with both the key and passphrase as arguments

Tags: ssh, bash

I am trying to run **ssh-add** by bash script on Alma9 server with restrictions.
The RSA key 4096 is on an SMB share so the file has broken permissions and the key is protected by a passphrase.
As the file is from a Windows share, so I can't alter the permissions directly. Thus **ssh-add** will not allow it.

I have tried a few ideas to get around this I found a couple of helpful pages.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46253162/add-ssh-key-from-variable

This helps, but I need to **also** add the passphrase

So something like

`ssh-add - <<< "${SSH_PRIVATE_KEY}" < add ${PASS}`

I have tried to use `expect` in the script: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4780893/use-expect-in-a-bash-script-to-provide-a-password-to-an-ssh-command

But that answer like :

```
eval(`ssh-agent`)

/usr/bin/expect
spawn ssh-add
expect "Enter passphrase for /root/.ssh/id_rsa:"
send "my_pass"
interact
```

But I need to stream the key into **ssh-add** and add the passphrase when needed.

Either I get boughed down with the `<<<` or quoting

I have also tried this: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/571741/how-to-pass-a-passphrase-to-ssh-add-without-triggering-a-prompt

`{ sleep .1; echo PASS; } | script -q /dev/null -c 'ssh-add - <<< "${SSH_PRIVATE_KEY}"'`

And this is where the quoting becomes a problem.

It is frustrating as I get parts A & B or B & C to work, but I need A & B & C so I have the key and pass entered into `ssh-add` and then I can use `ssh-agent` with the share key.

So I am looking for any help.  I have been staring at many sites to cobble a useful solution.

Thanks R.

Comment: Do you have any local FS to copy the file to?

Comment: I might be able to use a temporary file.  The goal was to not have any copies of the keys, but I might have to use a temporary file to get around the permissions issue.  I can copy or create a file from the share.  That is an option.

Comment: Here is the try for using 'script'  
```{ sleep .2; echo $PASSPHRASE; } | script -q /dev/null "ssh-add <<< $(echo $CURRENTROOTKEY)"``` 
Where the variables have the data needed